# What does it mean if my HTC Incredible's notification light flashes between green and amber?

Tags: notifications, htc-droid-incredible, notification-led

I was driving today and my phone was in its holder. At the time, I was using it for GPS and Pandora, and it was plugged in using my car charger. At one point, the notification LED began to flash in what looked like a regular pattern (but since I was driving, I can't be 100% sure), alternating between green and amber. I've never seen this before, and I had no notifications. What does it mean?

Comment: Was it flashing at an irregular rate? Its status could have been alternating between Full Battery and Charging.

Comment: I'll edit the question, but it was flashing in what appeared to be a regular pattern. I was driving, so I couldn't stare at it for a long period of time to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it means the battery is overheating.

Comment: Is there some way to check/confirm this?

Comment: I haven’t been able to find any official documentation on this but there are various reports that describe the same symptoms and causes. For example: http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-hero/6742-led-alternates-green-then-orange-what-does-mean.html and http://forum.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g/41858-led-blinks-orange-green-means-your-batter-has-overheated.html

Comment: Although there's no official documentation, the discussion forums seem to back this up. Unfortunately, I have no desire to test this out myself...until someone can find concrete reasons why this might not be the reason, I'm going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because it is advising that the Micro USB is connected to charge the battery, but the battery is not charging, temperature or other reason